# Error - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a problem working on my project.

I'm trying to read a data from an Excel file. It works fine when I'm trying to select rows which are greater than `Col1Value` but after I add `AND Gender = " + gender;` it gives me error "NO VALUE GIVEN FOR ONE OR MORE REQUIRED PARAMETERS" I cannot set a specific gender column because It is different on every excel file although column name is same and error appears when I'm trying to fill the DataSet.

```
if (boxGender.Text != "")

string gender = boxGender.Text;
string col1Name = lbl1stColumn.Text;


string Query = "select * from [data$] where " + 
               col1Name + " > " + Col1Value + 
               " AND Gender = " + gender;                                                
OleDbDataAdapter dacol1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, con);                        
    Column1Data.Clear();
    dacol1.Fill(Column1Data)
    lblStuCount1Col.Text = Column1Data.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: Beware of SQL injection

Comment: [Should we include tags in question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) ? : No. We should not. Should we write titles in **BOLD** ? : No We should not.

Comment: Only me will be using it so.. :)

Comment: Is `Gender` a string vlaue or numeric? if it is string `gender` should be in quotes. `col1Name` or `gender` null or blank when you run this?

Comment: @EimantasBaigys Develop good habits early so that you don't make mistakes when it actually matters and end up leaving a huge gaping security vulnerability in an application with important sensitive data.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk WHAT ABOUT CAPS?  ARE ALL CAPS OKAY?

Comment: @Servy Silly me... I wrote bold when I meant CAPS.  -_-' -1 Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing quotes in your SQL query:

```
string Query = "select * from [data$] where " + col1Name + " > '" + Col1Value + "' AND Gender = '" + gender +"'";
```

Note single quote (') symbols added.

Comment: Yeap that was the problem, Thank you Sir

Comment: When I execute this query it gets all data according to gender, however it does not filter e.g Male where 'col1Name > Col1Value' instead it shows all male.... ANY Suggestions?

Comment: @EimantasBaigys If you put a breakpoint in this line of code are values of col1name and Col1Value correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the string value in single quotes and the column names in square brackets:

```
string Query = "select * from [data$] where [" + 
               col1Name + "] > " + Col1Value + 
               " AND Gender = '" + gender + "'";
```

Comment: The column name in brackets shouldn't be require, right? There are no spaces and surely `col1Name` is not a keyword.

Comment: `col1name` is a variable, not a literal.  It could contain a value that has spaces.

Comment: col1Name is a variable containing 1 word only